# WhatsApp report by channel

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, whatsapp

I'm aware that in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, we can generate reports in Analytics Builder for email campaigns by navigating to the "Recent Email Sending Summary" tab. It's as simple as setting a date range, and from there, we can create reports detailing clicks, opens, and more.

However, I'm curious if there's a similar functionality for WhatsApp campaigns. Is there a straightforward way to generate a comparable report for all WhatsApp campaigns? I would greatly appreciate your assistance with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi There is no direct report available for WhatsApp in SFMC as of now, you can export the report using the automation studio .

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer is NO.

Long Answer below:
Currently, there are two ways to check or extract data from SFMC for WhatsApp activities:

1. **View** the aggregated data like Sends, deliveries,read, and failed statuses on the Journey builder screen
   [SF help text](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_whatsapp_analytics.htm&type=5)
2. **Data Extract** via Automation Studio: it provides attributes like ContactKey, MobileNumber, ChannelID,ActivityName, Status, Reason, unsubscribe details, Inbound Message Details
   [SF help text](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_whatsapp_data_extract.htm&type=5)